# Paste string when NA in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

Here's an example of my data :

```
my_df <- data.frame("R" = c("123", NA, NA, "456", "789", "123", NA),
                "D" = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "aze", "aze"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I'd like to do is whenever I have NA in the column "R" I want to paste the content in the column "D" in the last previous row where "R" was not NA.

Here's the expected result :

```
my_result <- data.frame("R" = c("123", "456", "789", "123"),
                    "D" = c("abcdefghi", "ijk", "lmn", "azeaze"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tidyverse**

```r
my_df <- data.frame("R" = c("123", NA, NA, "456", "789", "123", NA),
                    "D" = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "aze", "aze"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(tidyverse)
my_df %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(!is.na(R))) %>% 
  fill(R) %>%
  group_by(R, grp) %>%
  summarise(D = paste0(D, collapse = ""), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(grp) %>% 
  select(-grp)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   R     D        
#>   <chr> <chr>    
#> 1 123   abcdefghi
#> 2 456   jkl      
#> 3 789   mno      
#> 4 123   azeaze
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(my_df)[, grp := cumsum(!is.na(R))] %>% 
  .[, R := zoo::na.locf(R)] %>% 
  .[, list(D = paste0(D, collapse = "")), by = list(R, grp)] %>% 
  .[, grp := NULL] %>% 
  .[]

#>      R         D
#> 1: 123 abcdefghi
#> 2: 456       jkl
#> 3: 789       mno
#> 4: 123    azeaze
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I thought of that but the problem is that I can have duplicates and I don't want them to be grouped...

Comment: Then just switch the solution to use `mutate(g = cumsum(!is.na(R))) %>% group_by(g)`

Comment: updated the solution

Comment: Could shorten `data.table` solution to: `setDT(my_df)[, .(D = paste0(D, collapse = ""), R = first(R)), by = cumsum(!is.na(R))][, !"cumsum"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` in `sapply` after you have `split` `my_df$D` by `cumsum(!is.na(my_df$R))`.

```
i <- !is.na(my_df$R)
data.frame(my_df["R"][i,,drop=FALSE]
         , D = sapply(split(my_df$D, cumsum(i)), paste, collapse = ""))
#    R         D
#1 123 abcdefghi
#4 456       jkl
#5 789       mno
#6 123    azeaze
```